# Typo3 multiple sites using different file storages

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm running a TYPO3 installation that serves two mostly distinct sites (domain-a.org and domain-b.org). That all works fine except I would like to have two different file mounts or different default upload folders for each site. I know I can upload the file first and then add the file to content elements, but it would be convenient especially for editors if they could just be uploaded and sorted automatically by site.

And yes, I know I can change upload targets for users. But it's basically just one user who does all the editing of both sites. Otherwise the documentation isn't very helpful (as usual).

Comment: I think that this issue is related to your topic: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/83608; here it has been suggested to take a look at the extension https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/default_upload_folder

Comment: In User TSconfig you can use conditions, among other things PIDinRootline. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/UsingSetting/Index.html#condition-references

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Yes, thanks! That might at least work as a basis for a custom solution. I do wonder why a system that claims to have a very good multi site support is unable to store files on a per site basis but in a per user basis.

Comment: @JulianHofmann From what I understand from the many and very confusing Typo3 word inventions it would be on per user basis, which isn't really useful for my environment.

Comment: You can define the uploadfolder via User TSconfig. And in this configuration, you can use conditions. So, the setting for this user can depend on e.g. the PIDinRootline. Isn't that the desired goal?